# On a Biblical Citation in “A Memorial to a Christian Life''

Tags: biblical-basis, bible

I am reading [***A Memorial of a Christian Life***](https://ia802804.us.archive.org/1/items/amemorialchrist00luisuoft/amemorialchrist00luisuoft.pdf) by Ven. Louis of Granada.

On page 324, it is given:

*“Thou shalt not take a form contrary to thine own form” - Eccles. 14. v. 26.*

However, the Book of Ecclesiastes only has twelve chapters. Moreover, I could find nothing in any of these twelve chapters that resembles this quote.

Does anyone know where in the Bible the said verse in Memorial comes from?

Thank you.

Comment: I was going to guess Ecclesiasticus rather than Ecclesiastes, which has chapter 14 and v 26, but it reads "He shall set his children under her shelter, and shall lodge under her branches.".

Comment: Ecclesiastes 12:14 (transposition is the most common error in quoting scriptural texts) has a similar sentiment to the context, but the wording is otherwise : _For God shall bring every work into judgment, with every secret thing, whether it be good, or whether it be evil._.

Comment: @DJClayworth Actually, I recall seeing in this particular edition of *Memorial* that the abbreviation ``Eccl.'' was used to refer to Ecclesiasticus; and, in fact, in one of the chapter 5's, ``Eccles'' was used in regards to an Ecclesiasticus citation.